# How to write JSONdata to the html element in phonegap application?

Tags: php, android, json, cordova

I am trying receive the JSON data using PhoneGap application. I am using server **xampp php** server. On this server I have server code **api.php** for receiving data from database.  My laptop's IP address is *192.168.1.4* so the URL of this **local server**  is **http ://192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/api.php**".

I am able to receive the data using

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```

but I want to add this _email_id_ information to

```
<div id="email">Email_id< /div >
```

which is defined in **index.html**.

From my **Android phone I want to just log in and and receive the email_id of that user**. Please see the image of my database and and data receive on my phone using 
alert(JSON.stringify(response)).

My server code is **api.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("demo");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type']=="login"){
        $username=$_GET['UserName'];
        $Password=$_GET['Password'];
        $query="Select * from registration where UserName='$username' and Password='$Password'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $totalRows=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        if($totalRows>0){
            $recipes=array();
            while($recipe=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $recipes[]=array('User'=>$recipe);
            }
            $output=json_encode(($recipes));
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid format";
}
```

My PhoneGap application code is in **index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <title> Database Application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

               $("#btnLogin").click(function(){

               var userId = document.getElementById('id').value;
               var userPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;

                  $.ajax({
                      url:"http://192.168.0.106/Experiements/webservices/api.php",
                      type:"GET",
                      dataType:"json",
                      data:{type:"login", UserName:userId,Password:userPassword},
                      ContentType:"application/json",
                      success: function(response){                       
                           alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                              var userEmail = response[0].User.email; // Find the email from the JSON
                              var emailDiv = $("div#email"); // Find the div for email with jQuery selector
                              emailDiv.text(userEmail); // Put user's email as text to that div
                      },
                      error: function(err){
                          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                      }
                  })
               }); 
            });
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",OnDeviceReady,false);
        function OnDeviceReady(){
            //alert("cordova is loaded");
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
            User ID       : <input type="text" id="id" name="user" />
            User Password : <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
            <input type="button" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" value="Login"/>

            <div id="email">Email_id</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

DataBase: **demo**, user: **root**, password: **1234**, table: **registration**
[image]

Screen shot of my phone:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Above code is working code, I modify according to sanfor thanks to @sanfor,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood you correctly, what you want to do is to get the `email_id` from the response and put the content into the `div` called *email*.

What you need to do is to first get the user's email from the JSON object which is in your case *Array* with just one item. This first item of array again is *Object* which contains field called *email* which is exactly what we want. After that we need to locate the div from the DOM with [jQuery element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and insert the user's email in it. Example is found below.

```
var userEmail = response[0].User.email; // Find the email from the JSON
var emailDiv = $("div#email"); // Find the div for email with jQuery selector
emailDiv.text(userEmail); // Put user's email as text to that div
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I modify the code according to you, but it is not working.

Comment: @neelabhsingh: Sorry for that, I had . instead of # on the middle line. Fixed it now.