# How add dynamically JSON data to the JQuery Mobile List view in PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

**I am getting JSON data list of collage within given distance in K.M. Now I have to add this collage list to the JQuery Mobile List View**. In register page student information will fill. Then after pressing Register button javascript will execute and In Java script we are passing the distance as parameter, On server will fetch list of collage located within given distance. I intentionally did not mentioned longitude and latitude simplify reason. Letter We will pass two parameter current longitude and latitude instead of distance. Now fetched data which will in json formate I have to add this information to page **CollageOptions** under **ul view**. **Please tell me what should I write inside 
success: function(response)** in javascript.
 Structure of database is

[image]

```
<div data-role="page" id="register" data-theme="d" style="width: 100%;">           
    Name :<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="userName">
    Email: <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="eMail">
    Mobile: <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobNumber">
    Distance: <input type="text" id="distance_id" name="distance" />
    <a href="#CollageOptions" class="ui-btn" style="background-color: #B6B6BC; color: black;"                         
       id="btnReg">Register</a>
</div>
```

[image]

```
<div data-role="page" id="CollageOptions">
<div style="width: 100%; margin-top:21%; margin-left: 1%; color: black; id="details" data-  
 role="listview">

   <ul id="listOfCollage" data-role="listview">
        Here I have to list list of collage available with in given distance
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now suppose distance is 35 k.m. then list of collage will fetch

[image]

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("foodybuddy");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type']=="login"){
        $distanceInKM=$_GET['Distance'];       
        $query="Select * from collage where Distance<='$distanceInKM'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $totalRows=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        if($totalRows>0){
            $recipes=array();
            while($recipe=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $recipes[]=array('Chef'=>$recipe);
            }
            $output=json_encode(($recipes));
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid format";
}

<script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){  
               $("#btnReg").click(function(){  
                  var distance = document.getElementById('distance_id').value;                
                  $.ajax({ 
                              url:"http://192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/getBuddy.php", 
                              type:"GET", 
                              dataType:"json", 
                              data:{type:"login", Distance:distance}, 
                              ContentType:"application/json", 
                              success: function(response){



                              }, 
                              error: function(err){ 
                                  alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                              } 
                  }) //ajax
               });  //click
            }); //ready
    </script>
```

Comment: If you search SO you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: @Omar, thanks for your replay I am new in web technology, so please tell me best site because i urgently need it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjquery-mobile%5d%20listview%20ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an each loop to read the Json Data and prepare the list items

```
var output = ""; // declare an empty variable inside click function

$("#listOfFoodOptions").empty(); // empty the list

.
.
.

success: function(response){ 

$.each(response, function(index,value){ // loop through the data

output += "<li>"+value.Chef.Name+"</li>"; 

}); 

$("#listOfFoodOptions").append(output).listview().listview('refresh'); // refresh the list

}

.
.
.
```

.

Comment: @Tasos, thanks for your replay but where is Ajax like $.ajax({, Or we don't need  $.ajax({  In Post method, I am waiting for your reply...

Comment: @neelabhsingh  Its the simplified version you have exactlty, minus the GET ofcource. see here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @Tasos , I see your link it was HTTP post request but I need XMLHTTP request, sorry But I am  new in webTechnology, I got this project I need to complete it.

Comment: @Tasos As you say that GET will not work In this question(posted by me) I am using GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731448/how-to-write-jsondata-to-the-html-element-in-phonegap-application

Comment: @neelabhsingh you are correct. my bad.ill amend the answer to reflect that. anyway if you want to use GET then you use the (each) function to loop through data and make the list. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @Tasos, I was waiting for replay, thanks, Just I am telling What i want, I am fetching the list of collage from database for given Distance, So this collage list must be in different size depending on the distance, Now I have to added this information to the jquery mobile list, So please tell me How to handle dynamic list in success funtion(response),  I am waiting for your reply. Thanks..

Comment: sorry not request but distance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68284/discussion-between-tasos-and-neelabhsingh).

Comment: @Tasos, I am getting output like RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME. and Also Every time when I request it is added 2nd request RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME, 3rd request RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME RESONSE[0].CHEF.NAME